# ARKit keep object on screen corner always

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have simple object which Should be on TOP LEFT corner or TOP RIGHT corner of the screen

I have added SCNNode in pointOfView which shows it in centre of the screen But I want it to be in any of corner

What I did

```
    let ball = SCNSphere(radius: 0.05)
    let matirial = SCNMaterial()
    matirial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "image")
    ball.materials = [matirial]

    let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)
    ballNode.position = self.sceneView.pointOfView?.worldFront ?? SCNVector3(0,0,0) // cameraPosition == center.worldTransform
    ballNode.name = "ballCounter"
    self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(ballNode)
```

I tried `unprojectPoint` but ball is now completely vanished

```
let point = self.sceneView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(20, 20, self.sceneView.pointOfView!.worldFront.z))
print("point of unproject \(point)" )
let convertedPoints = point
ballNode.position = convertedPoints
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: was you able to figure this out ? I am struggling in this as well